# Why do I get this webscraping issue in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

**Right now I am working on my second web scraping project in python. The issue I am having is that I can not pull the flight prices from the website(Website will be in code, a point in the right direction will be great. **

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)

sats = 'https://www.google.com/travel/explore?tfs=CBsQAxooagwIAhIIL20vMGZyMHQSCjIwMjAtMDQtMjByDAgEEggvbS8wMTYwdxooagwIBBIIL20vMDE2MHcSCjIwMjAtMDQtMjdyDAgCEggvbS8wZnIwdHABQAFIAQ&curr=USD&gl=us&hl=en&authuser=0&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com'
browser.get(sats)
browser.title

browser.save_screenshot('/home/UrbanGuide/Desktop/test_flights.png')


soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html5lib")


cards = soup.select('div[class*=tsAU4e]')
cards[0]

print(card.select('h3')[0].text)
print(card.select('span[class*=price]')[0].text)
#the line of code above gives me the error message:IndexError                                #Traceback (most recent call last)
#<ipython-input-173-c949e249e30b> in <module>
#      2 for card in cards:
 #     3     print(card.select('h3')[0].text)
#----> 4     print(card.select('span[class*=price]')[0].text)

#IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: This usually means none of that type of element have been found, can you provide the page link?

Comment: I Will give you a hint that works for me almost every time I do something like this ;) ...1. Inspect the element really closely, 2. Get like 3 elements that are on the website the same ( like now, you have a price ) and try to find a pattern. 3. Try to be as itterative as possible ;) ... + A little tip: In my opinion, you should first play around with selenium as it is :) ( element.text might be hellful ;) ) ... Good luck in this project, I hope you finish it ^^ + gl in other projects too

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: The issue that I am having is that I can pull the names for the flights but I can not pull the prices. If I do pull the prices, I only get the first few trips and I still get the index error.

Comment: The page link: https://www.google.com/travel/explore?tfs=CBsQAxooagwIAhIIL20vMGZyMHQSCjIwMjAtMDQtMjByDAgEEggvbS8wMTYwdxooagwIBBIIL20vMDE2MHcSCjIwMjAtMDQtMjdyDAgCEggvbS8wZnIwdHABQAFIAQ&curr=USD&gl=us&hl=en&authuser=0&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com'

Answer (score 0):

Look at `cards[0]` (which I assume you meant to assign `card` to)

```
card = """
<div class="tsAU4e ">
 <div class="wIuJz">
  <h3 class="W6bZuc YMlIz">Nassau</h3>
  <div class="ZjDced CQYfx">
   <img alt="American" class="C5fbBf" height="16" 
src="//www.gstatic.com/flights/airline_logos/70px/AA.png" width="16"/>
   <span class="nx0jzf">1 stop</span>
   <span class="qeoz6e U325Rc"></span>
   <span class="Xq1DAb">6 hr 25 min</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="Q70fcd sSHqwe">
  <div class="MJg7fb">
   <span class="QB2Jof xLPuCe">
    <span aria-label="293 US dollars" data-gs="CidHSUNLQUJHLS0tLS0tLS0tcGZleTIxQUFBQUFGNTFhcTRONExSQUESATAaCwif5AEQAhoDVVNEKgoyMDIwLTA0LTIwMgoyMDIwLTA0LTI3OAhKBAgBEAE=">$293
    </span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
"""
```

Given that, `card.select('span[class*=price]')` will return an empty list so indexing the 0th element of the list will fail

Try inspecting each element more closely before you try and extract out information. This way you can see what you actually need to search for

Comment: I see what you are saying, the only thing is if I index card[0] and get a travel location, I should get the price for that ticket right?